# How to initialize a set from a vector and provide a compare function?

Tags: stl, c++17, libstdc++, std

I need to get the unique elements of a vector, sorted by a criteria implemented in a function. As you can see the vector, and the resulting set, "only" contain references to the objects to be sorted.

The following minimal example works, as long a I do not use the compare function ˋref_wrp_ltˋ.

```
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template <class T> constexpr bool ref_wrp_lt(const std::reference_wrapper<T>&lhs, const std::reference_wrapper<T>&rhs)
{
    return lhs.get() < rhs.get();
}

class A
{
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> my_vec = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>>();
    std::set<std::reference_wrapper<A>, bool(*)(const std::reference_wrapper<A>&, const std::reference_wrapper<A>&)> my_set(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), &ref_wrp_lt);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I provide it, it seems I have to provide an allocator. Is this really the case and if yes, how can I always use the default allocator?

P.S.: I am new to STL and object oriented programming in C++.

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part in the example code is an `operator<` for `class A`. Adding it ie. as follows makes the code compilable:

```
class A
{
    public:
    bool operator<(const A &other) {
        // TODO: add logic for comparison
        return false;
    }
};
```